# Laravel 5.5 feature test says it's missing a field when the factory provides it

Tags: php, laravel, testing, factory

My product factory contains a slug:

```
$factory->define(Product::class, function (Faker $faker) {
    return [
        'title'       => $faker->sentence(4, true),
        'slug'        => $faker->slug,
        'description' => $faker->paragraph,
    ];
});
```

My feature test uses the factory to make a new instance:

```
$product = factory(Product::class)->make();
$response = $this->post('admin/products/store', $product->toArray());
$editPage = $this->get($response->headers->get('Location'));
$editPage->assertSeeText($product->title);
```

When I run the test I get a SQL error saying the slug is missing:

```
Error creating product:SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 19 NOT NULL constraint failed: products.slug (SQL: insert into "products" ("title", "description", "updated_at", "created_at") values (Velit quisquam et accusamus debitis et., Aperiam sint architecto ut sit pariatur aliquid. Et et omnis perspiciatis. Est officiis accusamus enim ut rerum cumque., 2018-02-05 23:58:02, 2018-02-05 23:58:02))
```

The same approach works in my other feature tests. The test is run as an authenticated admin will all the necessary permissions.

Comment: Do you have guarding enabled on your model, and if so, is `slug` in `$fillable`?

Comment: Also, you might want to post the controller code that actually handles the database insertion of your model.

Comment: That was it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment because I don't have 50 reputation! 
I just wonder if you did the fillable thing in the product model or not

```
protected $fillable = ['slug'];
```

Comment: That was it. Thanks!